# geometry hard olympiad problem

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

[image]

Prove that $\left[BC\right]\:$ cross that $[AP]'s$ midpoint

Comment: Your diagram seems to have two points labeled A, and two labeled C.

Comment: tangent points is $A_1$ , $B_1$ and $C_1$

Comment: Okay so to make sure I understand this correctly, if we were to extend  line $BC$ such that it intersects line $AP$ at say point $D$ then $AD \cong DP$. Is this what you're trying to prove?

Comment: I try to prove it?

Comment: Ok well then good luck because I still don't know what it is you're trying to prove

Comment: Sir,i don't understand what is your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=AB'=AC'$, $b=BC'=BA'$ and $c=CA'=CB'$. Let $B'C'$ meet $AA'$ at $X$ and $BC$ at $Y$. There is a unique rectangle $AA'ZW$ such that $W$ lies on $BC$. Let $U$ be the center of this rectangle, so $UA=UA'=UZ=UW$.

We have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{|\triangle AB'C'|}{|\triangle ABC|}&=&\frac{a^2}{(a+b)(a+c)},\\
  \frac{|\triangle A'B'C'|}{|\triangle ABC|}&=&1
-\frac{|\triangle AB'C'|}{|\triangle ABC|}
-\frac{|\triangle A'BC'|}{|\triangle ABC|}
-\frac{|\triangle A'B'C|}{|\triangle ABC|}\\
    &=&1-\frac{a^2}{(a+b)(a+c)}-\frac{b^2}{(a+b)(b+c)}-\frac{c^2}{(a+c)(b+c)}\\
  &=&\frac{2abc}{(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Hence
$$
  \frac{A'X}{AX}=\frac{|\triangle A'B'C'|}{|\triangle AB'C'|}
    =\frac{2bc}{a(b+c)}.
$$
By Ceva's theorem,
$$
  1=\frac{CY}{YB}\cdot\frac{BC'}{C'A}\cdot\frac{AB'}{B'C}
    =\frac{YA'+c}{YA'-b}\cdot\frac{b}{a}\cdot\frac{a}{c}.
$$
Solving,
$$
  YA'=\frac{2bc}{c-b}.
$$
Let $\alpha=\angle AA'B$ and $p=AA'$. By the law of cosines,
$$
  a^2+2ab=p^2-2bp\cos\alpha,
$$
$$
  a^2+2ac=p^2+2cp\cos\alpha.
$$
Thus
$$
  p^2=\frac{(a^2+2ab)c+(a^2+2ac)b}{b+c}=a^2+\frac{4abc}{b+c},
$$
$$
  p\cos\alpha=\frac{a(c-b)}{b+c}.
$$
Hence
$$
  A'W=\frac{p}{\cos\alpha}=\frac{a(b+c)+4bc}{c-b}.
$$
This gives
$$
  UY=UA'-YA'=\frac12 A'W-YA'=\frac{a(b+c)}{2(c-b)}.
$$
Finally we can compute
$$
  \frac{AZ}{ZU}\cdot\frac{UY}{YA'}\cdot\frac{A'X}{XA}
    =2\cdot\frac{a(b+c)}{4bc}\cdot\frac{2bc}{a(b+c)}=1.
$$
By Ceva's theorem, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are collinear. But $B'$ and $C'$ also lie on the line $XY$. That is, $Z$ is the intersection of $B'C'$ and $A'Z$. Since $A'Z$ is perpendicular to $AA'$, $Z=P$. The midpoint of $AP$ is $U$ which lies on $BC$.